BACI Design Generalized Linear Mixed Model Issue with Autocorrelation and Overdispersion
I am working with a dataset that used a BACI design in R. The data was collected in 4 sub-watersheds (Subwatershed) and 5 hillslope positions that were nested in each sub-watershed (Position). I have created daily averages (WC_15cm_daily_avg) for each Date value (yyyy-mm-dd). I also have a column called Period (Cal or Trt) and one called Treatment (0 or 1) to indicate which period it was (Calibration or Treatment) and which treatment it was (Control or Thinned). I want to see if the harvest had an effect, which would show up in a significant interaction between Treatment and Period.
Because of repeated measures (the data was collected from 2016 to 2021 with daily values), there is autocorrelation present. I want to use a generalized linear mixed model to take this autocorrelation and random effects of Sub-watershed and Position into account. WC_15cm_daily_avg ranges from 0.05 to 0.4, so I am using a beta distribution. The issue is that when I use ar for the autocorrelation I end up with overdispersion. However, if I don't include anything for autocorrelation then the data is still heavily autocorrelated. Any thoughts? I am open to not using a generalized linear mixed model, but I need to be able to test if harvest had an effect (Period * Treatment) and I need to consider repeated measurements and autocorrelation. Here is the model and below is a snapshot of the data.
Create a Time column as a factor with explicit levels
data_subset$Time <- factor(1:nrow(data_subset), levels = 1:nrow(data_subset))
# Fit mixed-effects model with AR(1) correlation structure
model_ar1 <- glmmTMB(WC_15cm_daily_avg ~ Treatment * Period + 
                   ( 1 | Subwatershed/Position) +
                   ar1(Time + 0 | ID),
                  family = beta_family(link = "logit"),
                  data = data_subset)

# Summarize the model
 summary(model_ar1)

Family: beta  ( logit )
Formula:          WC_15cm_daily_avg ~ Treatment * Period + (1 | Subwatershed/Position) +  
     ar1(Time + 0 | ID)
 Data: data_subset

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
-44413.4 -44351.9  22215.7 -44431.4     6920 

Random effects:

Conditional model:
 Groups                Name        Variance  Std.Dev.  Corr      
 Position:Subwatershed (Intercept) 2.503e-09 5.003e-05           
 Subwatershed          (Intercept) 6.031e-08 2.456e-04           
 ID                    Time1       2.756e-01 5.250e-01 0.99 (ar1)
Number of obs: 6929, groups:  Position:Subwatershed, 15; Subwatershed, 3; ID, 15

Dispersion parameter for beta family (): 3.28e+04 

 Conditional model:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)         -1.50792    0.13357 -11.290   <2e-16 ***
Treatment           -0.02583    0.18376  -0.141    0.888    
PeriodTrt            0.63821    0.02143  29.783   <2e-16 ***
Treatment:PeriodTrt  0.03444    0.02919   1.180    0.238   

'data.frame':   6929 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ ID               : chr  "TRE1" "TRE1" "TRE1" "TRE1" ...
 $ Date             : Date, format: "2016-06-01" "2016-06-02" "2016-06-03" ...
 $ WC_15cm_daily_avg: num  0.323 0.321 0.32 0.32 0.319 ...
 $ Year             : int  2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 2016 ...
 $ Position         : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
 $ Subwatershed     : chr  "TRE" "TRE" "TRE" "TRE" ...
 $ Treatment        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Period           : chr  "Cal" "Cal" "Cal" "Cal" ...
 $ Time             : Factor w/ 6929 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:1164] 292 293 294 295 296 297 311 312 313 314      ...

..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:1164] "292" "293" "294" "295" ...
